# Javascript check if input field has value

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out how can Javascript check if input field has any value, then it removes class value "is-invalid".

I have this code so far:

```
<form>
<label for="inputName">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="is-invalid" id="inputName">
</form>

<script>
        var checkInput = document.getElementById("inputName");
        if (checkInput.value) {
        element.classList.remove("is-invalid");
        }
</script>
```

[image]

As you can see theres a red border (class="is-invalid") around the input. As soon as user puts any value in the inputfield, Javascript will remove class value "is-invalid".

Or might there be an easier option with jQuery?

Comment: checkInput.value !== "" with js, $("#inputName").val() !== "" with jQuery

Comment: if your formName is say "myForn" then why don't you check myForn.$invalid in your submit field

Comment: If you want to check when user types in: 
HTML: `<input onchange="check">`
script: `function check(e){e.target.value !== ""){...}}`

Comment: What exactly is the question here? It's not very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code. You have used

```
element.classList.remove("is-invalid");
```

which is wrong, you have to use it like

```
checkInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
```

You can use like this in javascript.

```js
function check(){
  var checkInput = document.getElementById("inputName");
  if (checkInput.value) {
    checkInput.classList.remove("is-invalid");
  } else {
    checkInput.classList.add("is-invalid");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<label for="inputName">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="is-invalid" id="inputName" onkeyup="check()">
</form>
```

In Jquery you can try like

```js
$('#inputName').keyup(function(e){
  if ($('#inputName').val()) {
    $('#inputName').removeClass("is-invalid");
  } else {
    $('#inputName').addClass("is-invalid");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="inputName">Username</label>
  <input type="text" class="is-invalid" id="inputName">
</form>
```

Comment: The Javascript method works, but do you have any idea how to update the class without clicking out of the input?

Comment: keyup will do it

Comment: Sorry, to bother you, but I have another problem. I have two inputs username and password. If I use two of these javascript codes, its ads and removes the "is-invalid" to both ids (inputName and inputPassword)

Comment: You can pass `this` inside the function and access that element using `this`, just search in google about `this` keyword to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to the element to know when it changes.

```
  var checkInput = document.getElementById("inputName");
    checkInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
      if (e.target.value!==''){
        e.target.classList.remove("is-invalid");
    }
  })
```